# install canopy on windows8

Tags: python, 64-bit, windows-8.1, canopy

I was installed a canopy (canopy-1.1.0-win-64) on the version of Windows 8(64bit)

but Execution error occurred and Message is:

```
error message ;

canopy intalled in an unsupported path
```

you seem to hava installed canopy in a path containing no-ascii characters.
this is not yet supported. please re-install to a new path that contains ascii characters only.

Comment: Hamad, if you open a Windows "Command Prompt" and type "set" then press the Enter key, what do you get? Please copy and paste the entire result (text, not screen shot) into your question.

Comment: oh thanks ! im solved last night . create a window account and retry. maybe using the wrong user name